# Automatically fullscreen display photo after recieving by user in telegram bot mobile

Tags: python-3.x, mobile, automation, fullscreen, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot in python3. It's based on the python-telegram-bot library. As part of the game concept, I need to send a photo to the user in mobile app, so that the user doesn't see the content of the photo. At this point, the uploaded image opens in Telegram app dialog box. And to open a photo in fullscreen mode, you need to poke your finger at the mobile screen. I want to automate the logic of displaying a photo in its original size. Is there a way to **automatically** open a photo full screen after being received by the user?
Below is code snippet of function

```
def send_card(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query_data = update.callback_query.data
    if query_data == "city":
        cards_list = glob('cards/cities/*.png');
    else:
        cards_list = glob('cards/animals/*.png');
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    cardname = choice(cards_list)
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open(cardname, "rb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Something like this would be up to the client.